# Firebase single value event listener return null every time

Tags: android, kotlin, null

I'm trying to get integer number from my firebase but every time when I'm trying to get the integer value by single value event listener it return Null..

I'm don't know what to do please help me thx.

[see the result of my function.... it returning null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDnsL.png)

[this is the value that i'm trying to get... but im getting null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfrMc.png)

this is my code: (Please Help Me)

```
roomName= intent.getStringExtra("Username").toString()
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
myRoomRef = db.getReference("rooms/$roomName/CountPlayers")
        myRoomRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                //error
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                num_of_player_TextV.text = dataSnapshot.getValue(Int::class.java).toString()
            }})
```

[Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()) error......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlSb.png)

Comment: have you tried this:

    num_of_player_TextV.text = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()

Comment: Yes it doesn’t work also..

Comment: still getting null? are you completely sure your path is correct? if yes, try this: Integer.valueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue())

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that this is the right path you can look also in the added pic and see that the right path is rooms -> roomname -> countplayer to get the count players variable. Also, Integer.valueOf(dataSnapShot.getValue()) didn't work see the new pic in my question

Comment: Ok I fixed it thx for your help man